# Типовой идентификатор внутри строки таблицы

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!
Есть таблица вида

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Имя</th>
        <th>Возраст</th>
        <th>Город</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input type="text" id='name' value="Винни Пух" readonly onClick="change(this)" onChange="alert(this.value)"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id='age' placeholder="10" readonly onClick="change(this)"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id='city' placeholder="Москва" readonly onClick="change(this)"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

и JS

```
var previous_input;
function change(referer){
    var id=document.getElementById(referer.id);
    if(typeof(previous_input) !== 'undefined'){
        previous_input.setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly');
    }
    id.removeAttribute('readonly');
    previous_input=id;
}
```

Нужно: по клику на поле убирать атрибут readonly у элемента, и потом, по onChange, проверять данные на валидность и отправлять ajax на сервер. Это я сделать смогу. Вопрос в следующем. Можно ли не задавать каждому полю в такой таблице ID? как по мне, это не очень-то производительно и кажется мне плохим тоном, но я не знаток и утверждать не могу. Вот бы назначить типовой идентификатор каждому инпуту внутри строки tr. И внутри нее искать. Это возможно?

Comment: `class`,  `name`, `data-`  https://learn.javascript.ru/css-selectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае вообще не нужен вызов *getElementById*, так как текущий элемент и так передается в обработчик

```
var previous_input;
function change(id){
    if(typeof(previous_input) !== 'undefined'){
        previous_input.setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly');
    }
    id.removeAttribute('readonly');
    previous_input=id;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Если эта форма не дублируется, то в использовании `id` нет ничего страшного, в данном случае будет наоборот только производительнее, чем другие селекторы.

Но если дублируется и нужно кроссбраузерно то лучше использовать jQuery (я не фанат таких предложений, но тут будет реальным геморроем сделать это без него)

```js
$('tr input').change(function(){ /* change, blur, focus */
  var row = $(this).closest('tr');
  alert(row.attr('data-id'));
  alert(row.find('input[name="age"]').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Имя</th>
        <th>Возраст</th>
        <th>Город</th>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id="vinnie">
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" value="Винни Пух"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="age" value="10" placeholder="10" readonly></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Москва" readonly></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что таких строк будет много, а jquery использовать особого желания нет. А что вообще почитать по поводу DOM и большого количества ID в нем?

Comment: Ну вообще есть правило что id на странице строго уникален. Если не надо поддерживать ie<9 то все эти манипуляции можно делать c querySelector, там есть и тот-же find и closest

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, где _есть и тот-же find и closest_?

Comment: @Grundy , да, тут неправильно ответил в комменте, https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/closest , + querySelector в глубь. В любом случае мой ответ глубже отвечает на вопрос и не стоит за это минусовать, при том что сами ответили на ...

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, минус как минимум за использование jQuery в ответе к вопросу, где метки jQuery нет